# Automator Python Script

Tags: python, macos, terminal, automator

I'm using Automator for a project and I'm facing an issue. How do I run an external python script with automator which includes some modules?

I tried doing it with 'Run Shell Script' but it shows some errors. I used '/bin/bash' as my shell. The command I used:

```
sudo python main.py
```

Error: The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified”

Please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be calling the correct python environment with that command. For example if you had python2 and python3 installed, then you might be calling your python2 environment when you meant to call the python3 environment.